# Can't connect to internet from DevStack instance

Tags: networking, openstack

I have installed OpenStack using DevStack on my local machine using VM. Then I have created an instance which can be connected from my VM using SSH. But when I try to update the system by using `sudo apt update` command, the instance cannot connect to internet and shows the following error.

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
```

This is my `local.conf` file contents.

```
[[local|localrc]]

ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
HOST_IP=10.0.2.15
FLOATING_RANGE=192.168.20.0/25

LOGFILE=$DEST/logs/stack.sh.log
LOGDAYS=2

SWIFT_HASH=66a3d6b56c1f479c8b4e70ab5c2000f5
SWIFT_REPLICAS=1
SWIFT_DATA_DIR=$DEST/data

#Enable swift services
enable_service s-proxy s-object s-container s-account
#Enable heat services
enable_service h-eng h-api h-api-cfn h-api-cw

#Enable heat plugin
enable_plugin heat https://opendev.org/openstack/heat

#Enable heat dashboard plugin
enable_plugin heat-dashboard https://opendev.org/openstack/heat-dashboard
```

Kindly mention do I need to add something else to configuration file or configure VM's network differently?